Create self-signed certificate in Azure Key Vault with JavaScript SDK
I found a Microsoft documentation page that explains how to create a self-signed certificate with PowerShell, and it fits my needs in that setup just right. You can find the guide here.
$certname = "{certificateName}"    ## Replace {certificateName}
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=$certname" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeySpec Signature -KeyLength 2048 -KeyAlgorithm RSA -HashAlgorithm SHA256

I’m looking to follow the same steps using the Azure JavaScript SDK. My goal is to programmatically create a self-signed certificate in Azure Key Vault. If anyone has any tips or a code example that shows how to achieve this with JavaScript, I would greatly appreciate it!
Thank you so much for your assistance!

Have you tried any code?

Pls Check below solution!

Any update, Is this solution works for you?

Initially, I created one Azure Key Vault resource and Enabled Azure role-based access control under my Resource Group:

To create New-SelfSignedCertificate you should have at least Key Vault Certificate Officer or Key Vault Administrator, Refer this MsDoc, Assigned Key Vault Certificate Officer to user at Resource group level like below:
// If packages and identity library is not installed, Run this command to install the packages and identity library in your terminal.

npm install @azure/identity
npm install @azure/keyvault-certificates


Use below JavaScript  SDK code to generate New-Self-Signed Certificate to Azure Key Vault:
const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require("@azure/identity");
const { CertificateClient } = require("@azure/keyvault-certificates");

const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

const vaultName = "<your-key-vault-name>";
const url = `https://${vaultName}.vault.azure.net`;

const client = new CertificateClient(url, credential);

const certificateName = "<edit-certificate-name-here>";

async function main() {
  console.log("Creating certificate...");

  // Create the certificate
  const createPoller = await client.beginCreateCertificate(certificateName, {
    issuerName: "Self",
    subject: "cn=MyCert",
  });
  
  // Wait for the creation to complete
  const certificate = await createPoller.pollUntilDone();
  console.log("Certificate is created successfully...");

  // Retrieve the latest version of the certificate
  const latestCertificate = await client.getCertificate(certificateName);

  // Log the details
  console.log("Certificate Details:");
  console.log("Name:", latestCertificate.name);
  console.log("Version:", latestCertificate.properties.version);
  console.log("Thumbprint:", latestCertificate.properties.x509Thumbprint?.toString("hex"));
  console.log("Created On:", latestCertificate.properties.createdOn);
  console.log("Expired On:", latestCertificate.properties.expiresOn);

}

main().catch((err) => {
  console.error("An error occurred:", err);
});




Response:

Also, I verified from Azure Portal, Certificate is created successfully.

References:
Azure SDK for JavaScript
Key Vault Certificate
Refer this Doc: To enable Azure RBAC permission on Key-Vault
